# Spring web app deploys on Gradle's embedded Jetty but not in standalone Jetty

Tags: spring-mvc, jetty, gradle

I have built a small web app using Gradle.  Things seemed to be going well using the embedded Jetty server, but not so well when I tried to copy the WAR file to a standalone server.

I used the gradle war plugin to assemble the war.

Running gradle jettyRunWar works fine.

Copying the war to the Jetty webapps folder and running Jetty fails with this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No such servlet servlet_name
```

But this very same servlet is found and used without issue in the embedded Jetty server.

The same issue happens if I manually copy the exploded war to the webapps directory.

The Spring web and Spring mvc libs are copied and present in the WEB-INF/libs directory, so it isn't an issue of not finding Spring (or is it?)

I'm using Jetty 9.1, and my web.xml file is configured for Servlets v3.

I'm also using Spring 3.2.  The web app I'm writing is a RESTful service, using the @Controller annotations to route requests.

This should be as simple as copying the war over, but it seems not to be.  At a bit of a loss at what to do here, any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the answer is staring you in the face...after posting I realized that I had my servlet-mapping before my servlet declaration.  While this did not present an issue for the Gradle Jetty (not sure why), it made Jetty unhappy.  Not sure why I changed the order to begin with...

In short, Jetty seemed to not find the servlet because it had not been declared yet.